# How do i send data from a Form on my website to my local Intranet?

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net

Here's my issue, I have just finished my website and i have a form on it that i send to myself via Email, everything is working fine except i want to make things easier for me and my team since i have to type all the date received from the forms to my local server, I have tried using php but i have no clue how to acces my local server from the website. My question is : How do i send the form directly to my server ?

PS: I do not need any specific code , i just need someone to put me on the right track

Comment: How could we help to simplify a script that we can't see ?

Comment: Like i said, there is no script, my form ( contains name, age ... ) is being sent via email and is working, then i type that data manually in my sql server since my webpage is hosted on a different server, my question is : Is there a way to do it without having to use email and typing it ( Send it to my local server using php or any other language or method  because i don't even know if it is possible) ?

Comment: Are the servers on the same network? Is the local intranet server exposed to the Internet, or can you expose it to the Internet? Does it have an API for posting data? There's a lot of unanswered questions here that make this too broad.

Comment: Thanks mason for the answer, I know too well that there is too many unanswered questions. Servers are not in the same network. Local intranet is not exposed to the internet but can be done if it means opening a port and making it accessible. I dont have an API for posting Data .

Comment: i ran into the same issue a while back and spent a while trying to get it to work and decided to go another route. instead of posting data to the local server why not try get the from the server instead or as a customer/ clients posts the form to email have it post to a sql database.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a submit button in your form and put url of your local server in the form eg.

```
<form action="url" method=POST>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" value="SendAllDATA"/>
</form>
```

or you can submit your form by using javascript

```
document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and sorry if i did not explain myself properly, My problem is my server is local and i do not know how to acces it from the website ( which is hosted on a different server ).

Comment: Check if you can access your local server IP on that remote server